# Jquery DataTables does not show up after following tutorial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables

PROBLEM FIXED FOR NOW.

I fixed it by deleting my javascript section for a sticky header that scrolls with the page.
i really don't know why my javascript is crappy when that code is in application.html.erb

---

My datatables will work when my application.html.erb looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Dummyapp1</title>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "contractens" %>
          <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <div>

    </head>

<body>
==rest of script==
```

and it does not work when my application.html.erb looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Dummyapp1</title>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
          <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "contractens" %>
          <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <div>

</div>

    <!-- If you have jQuery directly, then skip next line -->
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // If you have jQuery directly, then skip next line
    google.load("jquery", "1");

    function sticky_relocate() {
      var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
      var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
      if (window_top > div_top)
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick')
      else
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
      }
    // If you have jQuery directly, use the following line, instead
    // $(function() {
    // If you have jQuery via Google AJAX Libraries
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
      $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
      sticky_relocate();
      });
    </script>

    </head>

<body>
```

I follow this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast) Tutorial for datatables in rails. i had this in my other app. there it works fine.
I did the same thing as the other app but it is showing me text instead of the actual table.

Here´s my view for the table:

```
    <h1>Listing contracten</h1>

    <table id="contractens" class="display">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Omschrijving</th>
            <th>Datumingang</th>
            <th>Contractduur</th>
            <th>Opzegtermijn</th>
            <th>Betalingstermijn</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
      <%= @contractens.each do |contracten| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= contracten.naam %></td>
        <td><%= contracten.omschrijving %></td>
        <td><%= contracten.datumingang %></td>
        <td><%= contracten.contractduur %></td>
        <td><%= contracten.opzegtermijn %></td>
        <td><%= contracten.betalingstermijn %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<%= link_to "Nieuw", new_contracten_path %>
```

and my javascript files are filled in correct.

here´s a screenshot of the issue:

[image: issue]

Hope you can help me :)

EDIT: it should look like this with no css:

[image]

and it should look like this with css:

[image]

This is my contractens.js.coffee :

```
jQuery ->
        $('#contractens').dataTable
          sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
          bJQueryUI: true
```

This is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree .
```

And this is my application.css:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
*= require_tree .
*/
```

EDIT 2:

when i have a javascript function to hide a div when clicking a checkbox. when i have

```
jQuery ->
        $('#contractens').dataTable
```

in my contractens.js.coffee it does work, but when i have:

```
jQuery ->
        $('#contractens').dataTable
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
        bJQueryUI: true
```

it does not work either. so something is blocking the jquery i guess.

Comment: did you called `$('#contractens').dataTable()`   ?

Comment: yes i did in my contractens.js.coffee file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @contractens.each do |contracten| %>
```

for

```
<% @contractens.each do |contracten| %>
```

The `<%= %>` tag set is used when you want output.

Comment: Strange but the text is now gone, i still can't see the table

Comment: Why strange? You were printing the contractens instance variable when using <%= %>.

Comment: no i mean strange that the table is still not showing after i editted it

Comment: i also expected that my other javascript code in my application.js isn't working when i have the jquery command in de contractens.js.coffee file, i think it's blocking each other in some way.

Comment: Please explain better what's your problem, edit your question if necessary.

Comment: you saw the railscasts example? i did everything right and it works in my other project. but the table is not showing. only the records

Comment: I guess.. you missed the CSS??

Comment: no i don't because when i did not have the css i should be able to see the searchbox and the pagination.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same Issue I changed this one:
 in my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree .
```

TO

```
//= require jquery
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

And it works now.

Comment: @KeesSonnema Yup :) its only for those people who might have this type of issue.

Comment: In my case it was a bugging js file. but it's helpful anyway :) thanks for mentioning.